# scala extends depending on parameter

Tags: scala, generics

I wonder if such thing is possible with scala:
Suppose I have following classes:

```
trait Condition
trait BuyCondition extends Condition
trait SellCondition extends Condition

class OrCondition[C <: Condition](c1: C, c2: C) extends Condition
```

is this possible to make it working like this:

```
val buyOr: BuyCondition = new OrCondition[BuyCondition](bc1, bc2)
val sellOr: SellCondition = new OrCondition[SellCondition](sc1, sc2)
```

basically I would like OrCondition to be either Sell or Buy one depending on it's type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using [phantom types](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/01/31/going-rogue-part-2-phantom-types/)

Here is an example

```
// Define a base trait for the condition phantom type
object Condition {
  trait Type
}

// The Condition is paramaterised by the phantom type
trait Condition[T <: Condition.Type]

// Define Buy/Sell types
trait BuyType extends Condition.Type
trait SellType extends Condition.Type

// defin the buy/Sell conditions
type BuyCondition = Condition[BuyType]
type SellCondition = Condition[SellType]

class OrCondition[T <: Condition.Type](c1: Condition[T], c2: Condition[T]) extends Condition[T]

val bc1, bc2 = new BuyCondition {}
val sc1, sc2 = new SellCondition {}

val buyOr: BuyCondition = new OrCondition(bc1, bc2)
val sellOr: SellCondition = new OrCondition(sc1, sc2)
```

Note they are called phantom types because the types BuyType and SellType are never instanciated at runtime they only exist for the compiler